# React library problem with importing CSS stylesheet

Tags: reactjs, import, leaflet

i am using https://github.com/0wczar/airframe-react and i want to implement there a map with react-leaflet library. When i am trying to import import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"; to style my map i got error like this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css 3:0
```

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* required styles */
|

> .leaflet-pane,
>   | .leaflet-tile,
>   | .leaflet-marker-icon,

What should i do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have css-loader and style-loader as your dev-dependency, if not install them with `npm install --save-dev style-loader` and then check your webpack config, adding this to your webpack.config.js will do

```html
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I do not have webpack.config.js but i have postcss.config.js and I installed style-loader and added code there like that:                                                  
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
       ]
    },
};

Comment: You will have to specify your post-css config to webpack for the post-css config to actually make effect as specified here https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#usage , try creating webpack.config.js file on the root folder and follow the docs. Hope that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using webpack. If so, you'll need to add a [webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/) to handle importing CSS files.

You should be able to use [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#root) for your current problem.